# android layout seperate resource folder

Tags: android

Suppose i have a file in res/layout

```
<com.dog.cat.SomeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw"
    android:id="@+id/SomeView"
    style="@style/SomeStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

and I want a similair layour in res/layout-sw600dp

```
<com.dog.cat.SomeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw"
    android:id="@+id/SomeView"
    style="@style/SomeStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding_left="10dp"
/>
```

I only added android:padding_left="10dp" in the second file. Is there any way to add the first file to the second without retyping all the other attributes like so?

```
 <com.dog.cat.SomeLayout
    //include all attributes in one line
    android:padding_left="10dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another style something like:

```
<style name="SomeStyle.SixHundredDP">
    //Put other attributes here
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Now for layout in res/layout-sw600dp:

```
<com.dog.cat.SomeLayout
    //Other attributes for this view
    style="@style/SomeStyle.SixHundredDP"
/>
```

Also you can have different value folders for different screen sizes just like layouts. For example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983814/can-styles-be-different-for-different-screen-sizes).